# Why does my Linux version name read Linaro instead of Xubuntu and how can I fix it?

Tags: xubuntu, custom-distributions, linaro

I have Xubuntu 12.04 installed. When I run any updates or installs, I do receive strange warnings touching "Linaro"  and software-center is not able to run with following error:

```
:~$ software-center
  ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
     from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
     from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
     import softwarecenter.distro
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
     distro_instance = _get_distro()
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 169, in _get_distro
     module = __import__(distro_id, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
 ImportError: No module named Linaro
 WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-9MI6cW/pkcs11: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 140, in <module>
     from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 50, in <module>
     from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
     import softwarecenter.distro
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
     distro_instance = _get_distro()
   File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 169, in _get_distro
     module = __import__(distro_id, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
 ImportError: No module named Linaro
```

And on the boot, there are "Linaro" not "Xubuntu" distribution. I guess, that this change come when I changed stable kernel to current kernel, when my kernel was in conflict with extended nvidia driver. Everything else works well.. so it is not a big issue, just weird.

I thought that Linaro distribution is targeted to ARM processors. How this distribution name come to me I do not know. What I can do to get back to Xubuntu distribution name?

Added:

```
 $ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Linaro
 Description:   Linaro 12.11
 Release:   12.11
 Codename:  precise

 $ python -c 'import platform; print platform.linux_distribution()'
 ('Linaro', '12.11', 'precise')
```

I'm pretty sure, that I have 12.04 Xubuntu installed...

```
 $ more /etc/lsb-release
 DISTRIB_ID=Linaro
 DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.11
 DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
 DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linaro 12.11"

 $ dpkg-query -W base-files
 base-files 6.5ubuntur6linaro12.11

 $ apt-cache policy base-files
 base-files:
   Instalovaná verze: 6.5ubuntur6linaro12.11
   Kandidát:          6.5ubuntur6linaro12.11
   Tabulka verzí:
  *** 6.5ubuntur6linaro12.11 0
         500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linaro-maintainers/overlay/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      6.5ubuntu6.5 0
         500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
      6.5ubuntu6 0
         500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

you are right, looks like I have their linakro kernel, what did solve my kernel-nvidia problem, but something more was added... But I have no other troubles, than misfunctional software center, so it is not seriously messed up.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to add the output of the following commands? `lsb_release -a` and `python -c 'import platform; print platform.linux_distribution()'`

Comment: Also, the contents of the file `/etc/lsb-release`

Comment: Looks like you installed Linaro (that is ARM) OR added a PPA for Linaro that seriously messed up your system. 12.11 is their latest release: http://www.linaro.org/linaro-blog/2012/11/29/linaro-12-11-now-available/

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/lsb-release`, the output of `dpkg-query -W base-files` and the output of `apt-cache policy base-files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough to edit /etc/lsb-release to its original content:

```
 DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
 DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
 DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
 DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Xubuntu 12.04"
```

And `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` went finally ok. I always omit to touch it as the computer should work on daily basis. This was my last try prior to decision of re-install or attempt to fix it. So it was finally fixed so so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Linaro overlay PPA (ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay) installed, which supplies a replacement `base-files` package, which has replaced your system's reported distribution name with Linaro.

If you want to install only specific packages from the overlay for purposes unrelated to the overlay's purpose, you can [use apt pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to prevent automatic upgrades to packages from the PPA. For example: you could create a file called `/etc/apt/preferences.d/linaro-overlay-pin` with the following contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-linaro-maintainers-overlay
Pin-Priority: 400
```

This will stop packages automatically upgrading when the PPA supplies more recent version numbers for them. Then you can install the packages from the PPA that you specifically want by specifying their version numbers:

```
sudo apt-get install foo=1.2-1
```

But since you've already upgraded `base-files` from the PPA without pinning, I'm not sure what else you might have upgraded, and what you'll need to downgrade manually.

Comment: ok, so and now what..., i will remove the source and I will upgrade to 13.xx probably this will work fine.